# Creating Buttons that Appear Raised in CSS

Tags: css

I'm converting an image based button into a CSS only button for an application that I'm working on.  Here's an example of the current image:

Enlarged Size:

[image: Enlarged Image]

Base Size:

[image: Base Size]

And here's where I'm at so far: http://dabblet.com/gist/3098607

What I'm having trouble replicating is the fact that the button has a shadow that makes it appear raised up a little. I've had no luck trying to replicate this with `box-shadow`.

Anybody have any ideas how I can get replicate this effect?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your image is stretched. Can you please post image without distortion? Now I can't understand, what's wrong with CSS.

Comment: @fedosov I updated my question with the base size.

Comment: How does this look: `box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(154, 147, 113, 0.95);` ?

Comment: @Tom That looks better than what I have but it still doesn't get the effect I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the beveled edge on the inside of the button to make it look raised.

Comment: I see. I don't know how to do it in pure CSS, using a **single element** and **without images**. Why do you want to do it like this anyway? What's wrong with styling a button element using images?

Comment: To avoid the excess HTTP requests.  There are a lot of different colors and types of buttons so they add up.

Comment: @TJVanToll how about inlining the images in your HTML or CSS? You can encode them in base64. Another option is to use inline SVG. That would be a bit more human-readable.

Comment: I like that idea and I can try that.  I want to keep things simple but I guess if what I'm trying to accomplish isn't going to be feasible with `box-shadow` I'll have to go down that route.  Thanks.

Comment: @TJVanToll you could also try to combine `box-shadow` with CSS 3D transformations somehow. No clue how it might turn out. Just an idea.

Comment: @TJVanToll I have updated my answer. Please, [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454786/183431) at the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use http://css3ps.com/ — this service can try to mimic your photoshop layer style. Also there is alternative PS plugin http://csshat.com/ (but not free), that helped me alot.

**UPDATE:**

[Created JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/xepX4/2/), trying to implement you button in CSS3. Please, write some feedback — are these the droids you're looking for?

Maybe shadow must be displaced to the left by 1px, but that's not the point.

**UPDATE 2:**

Or, maybe (I am repeatedly rereading question trying to figure out necessary behaviour), you'll like this: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/xepX4/3/).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/xdWmd/4/
It uses a little bit of CSS to make it look a bit raised.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like to accomplish this with one element.